# HTTP PUT request in Python using JSON data

Tags: python, json, http, put

I want to make PUT request in Python using JSON data as

```
data = [{"$TestKey": 4},{"$TestKey": 5}]
```

Is there any way to do this?

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://localhost:6061/data/'

data = '[{"$key": 8},{"$key": 7}]'

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

response = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

res = response.json()

print(res)
```

Getting this error

`requests.exceptions.InvalidHeader: Value for header {data: [{'$key': 4}, {'$key': 5}]} must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'list'>`

Comment: Have a look for http://www.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your `data` is already a JSON-formatted string. You can pass it directly to `requests.put` instead of converting it with `json.dumps` again.

Change:

```
response = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

to:

```
response = requests.put(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Alternatively, your `data` can store a data structure instead, so that `json.dumps` can convert it to JSON.

Change:

```
data = '[{"$key": 8},{"$key": 7}]'
```

to:

```
data = [{"$key": 8},{"$key": 7}]
```

Comment: But this will not change the Content-Type in the request header to application/json

Comment: @dumbledad Why not? It's defined in the `headers` dict as posted in the OP's question.

Answer (score 10):

HTTP methods in the `requests` library have a `json` argument that, when given, will perform `json.dumps()` for you and set the Content-Type header to `application/json`:

```py
data = [{"$key": 8},{"$key": 7}]
response = requests.put(url, json=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Python examples

I used the following script to update mapped IP for a VIP object in FortiGate 
firewall. 

import requests
import urllib3

def update_vip(current_vip, new_vip, new_ip):
    urllib3.disable_warnings()        # disable HTTPS certificate verify warning
    json_body = {
        "name": new_vip,
        "id": 65535,
        "mappedip": [
            {
                "range": new_ip
            }
        ]
    }
    fgt_url = ("https://<FGT_IP>/api/v2/cmdb/firewall/vip/" + current_vip +
               ("?access_token=<accesstoken>"))
    res = requests.put(fgt_url, json=json_body, verify=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    current_vip = "VIP_Collector_SSH"
    new_vip = "VIP_Collector_SSH"
    new_ip = "172.16.31.32"
    update_vip(current_vip=current_vip, new_vip=new_vip, new_ip=new_ip)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).